# Query is slow in application but fast in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, performance

stored procedure is running slow in application but fast in SSMS...
i have enabled SET ARITHABORT ON in stored procedure and it ran very fast from application in QA but still slowness in production ...we are running the stored proc from application in Read only database ( always on AG group )...

Things we have done so far:

1. Generated the both plans from plan cache (plan from SSMS and Application)
2. Cleared the plan for application procedure
3. Ran the procedure from application again but still it is slow and generating the plan with ARITHABORT as False.
4. Cleared both plans ( SSMS and Application ) and ran the procedure from application, still slow.
5. Altered the procedure , recompiled and created/dropped the procedure.
6. Stats were up to date.

Can anyone please help me on this ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64662/discussion-on-question-by-robin16-query-is-slow-in-application-but-fast-in-ssms).

Comment: Rescued from the comments scrap heap, the OP's query plans: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0a9e0ae1a41201f39fd199ca0851ecb5